# How to make lines in d3 line charts smoother?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, line

I have a small visual issue with a d3 line chart.

Maybe anyone has a short solution for this:

I want to have the three lines below smoother than they are.

[image]

I rather want to have the lines to look like this:

[image]

I already checked, that it is not the stroke-width which leads to this wrong visual behaviour.

If the question is unclear: Basically, I want to achieve a higher resolution of the chart, which looks like it consists of larger pixels.

This is the code, that leads to this result:

```
var temp = g.selectAll(".temp")
        .data(stationData)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "temp");

    let values = stationData.map(function(d){
        return {
            "hour": parseFloat(d.hour),
            "temperature": parseFloat(d.avgtemp)
        }
    });
    temp.append("path")
        .attr("id", "avgtemp")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(values);
        })
    temp.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {value: values[values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.hour) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
        .text("Avg Temperature");


    values = stationData.map(function(d){
        return {
            "hour": parseFloat(d.hour),
            "temperature": parseFloat(d.mintemp)
        }
    });
    temp.append("path")
        .attr("id", "mintemp")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(values);
        })
    temp.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {value: values[values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.hour) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
        .text("Min Temp");

    values = stationData.map(function(d){
        return {
            "hour": parseFloat(d.hour),
            "temperature": parseFloat(d.maxtemp)
        }
    });
    temp.append("path")
        .attr("id", "maxtemp")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(values);
        })
    temp.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {value: values[values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.hour) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
        .text("Max Temp");
```

Comment: Since you have not shared your code, I am not sure what the real problem. But still, I have seen similar issues in d3 charts, when multiple paths are drawn with the same d attribute. Confirm there are no such duplicate paths in your chart.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I totally forget, that it will look like this, when you have multiple instances..

I had a problem with a selectAll().enter(data) statement!

Now its working thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `shape-rendering` attribute of your generated SVG.

http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/248b7a374015f95790eb/

> Use the rendering key in the .shape() method to further control SVG
>   shape-rendering on all shapes generated in a D3plus visualization.

```
.shape({
      "rendering":"optimizeSpeed" // fine-tune SVG shape rendering
    })
```

for more details on SVG's Shape rendering [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering)

resources :

https://coderwall.com/p/ufldzw/for-crisp-edges-use-anything-but-crispedges

Answer (score 1):

The problem was pretty easy to fix:

I had a d3 statement within my code, that added the same diagram multiple times. Actually the number of data items within my data set, which was due to this code snippet:

```
  var temp = g.selectAll(".temp")
        .data(stationData)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "temp");
```

The result is now:

[image]

What I basically had to change was to replace all **temp** variables with **g**, which is the parent of current **temp** and the child of **svg**:

```
var temp = g.selectAll(".temp")
        .data(stationData)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "temp");

    let values = stationData.map(function(d){
        return {
            "hour": parseFloat(d.hour),
            "temperature": parseFloat(d.avgtemp)
        }
    });
    g.append("path")
        .attr("id", "avgtemp")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(values);
        })
    g.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {value: values[values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.hour) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
        .text("Avg Temperature");


    values = stationData.map(function(d){
        return {
            "hour": parseFloat(d.hour),
            "temperature": parseFloat(d.mintemp)
        }
    });
    g.append("path")
        .attr("id", "mintemp")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(values);
        })
    g.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {value: values[values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.hour) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
        .text("Min Temp");

    values = stationData.map(function(d){
        return {
            "hour": parseFloat(d.hour),
            "temperature": parseFloat(d.maxtemp)
        }
    });
    g.append("path")
        .attr("id", "maxtemp")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(values);
        })
    g.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {value: values[values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.hour) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
        .text("Max Temp");
```